I am trying a sample project on EIP2535 Diamond Proxy Pattern and I met with this issue
These are the files in my project:
Deploy.js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const [signer0] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  const address0 = await signer0.getAddress();
  console.log("Deployer address:", address0);
  // Deploy DiamondCutFacet
  const DiamondCutFacet = await hre.ethers.deployContract("DiamondCut");
  const diamondCutFacet = await DiamondCutFacet.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("DiamondCutFacet deployed at:", diamondCutFacet.target);
  // Deploy DiamondProxy with DiamondCutFacet address
  const DiamondProxy = await hre.ethers.deployContract("DiamondProxy", [diamondCutFacet.target]);
  const diamondProxy = await DiamondProxy.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("DiamondProxy deployed at:", diamondProxy.target);
  // Deploy AdditionFacet
  const AdditionFacet = await hre.ethers.deployContract("AdditionFacet");
  const additionFacet = await AdditionFacet.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("AdditionFacet deployed at:", additionFacet.target);
  // Deploy SubtractionFacet
  const SubtractionFacet = await hre.ethers.deployContract("SubtractionFacet");
  const subtractionFacet = await SubtractionFacet.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("SubtractionFacet deployed at:", subtractionFacet.target);
  // Attach DiamondCutFacet to the Proxy
  const diamondCut = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("DiamondCut", diamondProxy.target);
  // Add facets
  // Call diamondCut for AdditionFacet
  // Prepare facets and actions
  const facets = [
    {
      facetAddress: additionFacet.target,
      functionSelectors: ["0x771602f7"], // Add selectors for AdditionFacet
    },
    {
      facetAddress: subtractionFacet.target,
      functionSelectors: ["0x3ef5e445"], // Add selectors for SubtractionFacet
    },
  ];
  const actions = [0, 0]; // 0 corresponds to FacetAction.Add
  // Call diamondCut
  await diamondCut.diamondCut(
    facets, // Pass array of Facet structs
    actions, // Pass corresponding actions
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", // _init
    "0x" // _calldata
  );
  console.log("Facets attached successfully!");
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});

DiamondCutFacet.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// import "./DiamondStorage.sol";
interface IDiamondCut {
    enum FacetAction { Add, Replace, Remove }

    struct Facet {
        address facetAddress;
        bytes4[] functionSelectors;
    }

    function diamondCut(
        Facet[] calldata _facets,
        FacetAction[] calldata _actions,
        address _init,
        bytes calldata _calldata
    ) external;
}

contract DiamondCut is IDiamondCut {
    mapping(bytes4 => address) public facets;

    function diamondCut(
        Facet[] calldata _facets,
        FacetAction[] calldata _actions,
        address _init,
        bytes calldata _calldata
    ) external override {
        require(_facets.length == _actions.length, "Facets and actions length mismatch");
        
        for (uint i = 0; i < _facets.length; i++) {
            if (_actions[i] == FacetAction.Add) {
                addFacet(_facets[i]);
            } else if (_actions[i] == FacetAction.Replace) {
                replaceFacet(_facets[i]);
            } else if (_actions[i] == FacetAction.Remove) {
                removeFacet(_facets[i]);
            }
        }


        if (_init != address(0)) {
            (bool success, ) = _init.call(_calldata);
            require(success, "Initialization failed");
        }
    }

    function addFacet(Facet memory _facet) internal {
        for (uint i = 0; i < _facet.functionSelectors.length; i++) {
            facets[_facet.functionSelectors[i]] = _facet.facetAddress;
        }
    }

    function replaceFacet(Facet memory _facet) internal {
        removeFacet(_facet);
        addFacet(_facet);
    }

    function removeFacet(Facet memory _facet) internal {
        for (uint i = 0; i < _facet.functionSelectors.length; i++) {
            delete facets[_facet.functionSelectors[i]];
        }
    }
}

IDiamondCut.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IDiamondCut {
    enum FacetAction { Add, Replace, Remove }

    struct Facet {
        address facetAddress;
        bytes4[] functionSelectors;
    }

    function diamondCut(
        Facet[] calldata _facets,
        FacetAction[] calldata _actions,
        address _init,
        bytes calldata _calldata
    ) external;
}

DiamondStorage.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library DiamondStorage {
    bytes32 constant DIAMOND_STORAGE_POSITION = keccak256("diamond.standard.diamond.storage");

    struct Storage {
        mapping(bytes4 => address) selectorToFacet;
        address[] facets;
    }

    function getStorage() internal pure returns (Storage storage ds) {
        bytes32 position = DIAMOND_STORAGE_POSITION;
        assembly {
            ds.slot := position
        }
    }
    
    function getFacets() external view returns (address[] memory) {
        // Access the diamond storage
        DiamondStorage.Storage storage ds = DiamondStorage.getStorage();
        return ds.facets;
    }

}

DiamondProxy.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./DiamondCutFacet.sol";
import "./DiamondStorage.sol";

contract DiamondProxy {
    address public diamondCutFacet;

    // Initialize proxy with DiamondCutFacet address
    constructor(address _diamondCutFacet) {
        diamondCutFacet = _diamondCutFacet;
    }

    // Delegate calls to DiamondCutFacet
    fallback() external payable {
        address facet = diamondCutFacet;  // The facet address where the function is implemented
        require(facet != address(0), "Facet not found");
        (bool success, ) = facet.delegatecall(msg.data);
        require(success, "Function call failed");
    }
    receive() external payable{}
}

Addition.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract AdditionFacet {
    function addition(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

Subtraction.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SubtractionFacet {
    function subtract(uint256 a, uint256 b) external pure returns (uint256) {
        return a - b;
    }
}

I am getting the function selector using:
const signature_add = "add(uint256,uint256)";

const selector_add = ethers
  .keccak256(ethers.toUtf8Bytes(signature_add))
  .slice(0, 10);

console.log("signature_add : ", selector_add); // Outputs: 0x771602f7

And my issue is, when I try to interact with the contract using this Hardhat script:
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  // Replace with the deployed DiamondProxy address
  const diamondProxyAddress = "0x4ed7c70F96B99c776995fB64377f0d4aB3B0e1C1";

  // Use the AdditionFacet ABI to interact with the proxy
  console.log("addition")
  const additionFacet = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("AdditionFacet", diamondProxyAddress);

  try {
    // Call add function (delegated to AdditionFacet via proxy)
    const addResult = await additionFacet.add(5, 3);
    console.log("Addition Result:", addResult.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("AdditionFacet call failed:", error.message);
  }

  // Use the SubtractionFacet ABI to interact with the proxy
  const subtractionFacet = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("SubtractionFacet", diamondProxyAddress);

  try {
    // Call subtract function (delegated to SubtractionFacet via proxy)
    const subtractResult = await subtractionFacet.subtract(9, 4);
    console.log("Subtraction Result:", subtractResult.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("SubtractionFacet call failed:", error.message);
  }
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});

I am getting this error:
Error: AdditionFacet call failed: additionFacet.add is not a function


This question has formatting errors. Can you double check Markdown?

Hi Mikko, May I know what type of formatting errors. I cross checked it. Thanks for responding ☺️

There is no question in plain text, like in all other questions

In your AdditionFacet contract, you've named the function addition instead of add.
So, you either need to rename the function to add and redeploy your AdditionFacet contract, or you need to call additionFacet.addition in your Hardhat interaction script.

Hi Syed, Thanks for editing and I renamed it too as your instruction but the error shows same

Have you renamed your contract function or the one that you’re calling in the script?

Yes Syed., I've tried it

Okay, but I’m asking which one you did: 1. Did you rename your contract function to add?
Or, 2. Did you change the function name to additionFacet.addition in your Hardhat interaction script?
